# Python | PyQt5 QWebEngineView() webpack vue js (error localstorage is not supported)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, vuejs2, local-storage, pyqt5

I try to create browser for my application using **vue2**. Im using **PyQt5** version 5.9.2 and use module **QtWebEngineWidgets**. If i trying access my application using vue2 in **development** get blank page and in production mode i get same error, in console show error like this

> js: Local storage is not supported

here my code:

```
    webSetting = QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()
    webSetting.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
    webSetting.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)

    webView = QWebEngineView()
    webProfile = QWebEngineProfile(webView)
    webPage = QWebEnginePage(webProfile, webView)

    webView.setPage(webPage)
    # webProfile.setHttpUserAgent('XXXX')
    webView.load(QUrl("http://localhost:8081/#"))
    webView.show()
```

Environment: Python 3.5, PyQt5.9, Ubuntu16.04

I dont know what's wrong. Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: I have used the following code for my test: https://github.com/showonne/vue2-example and I have not had problems, Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/TuVvG, You could share your vue2 project to check if I have the same problem as yours.

Comment: Thanks for answer @eyllanesc. This link is my main.js code https://paste.ofcode.org/UVWx2kr28ibD5CgbhaZUve. I think because QtWebEngine cannot supported **local storage** or maybe just off. But if I running project belongs to someone else, browser running normal.

Comment: You can share the complete project of vue2 in a zip, I do not want to spend time completing the code.

Comment: I will send to your email sir @eyllanesc. Please send your email

Comment: Upload it to dropbox, drive or similar and share the link.

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc this my link downloa project  https://app.box.com/s/hfq7a2bcrkv20wcdxsnby4viwgt85pjj

Comment: @eyllanesc  i forget it, to access first http://localhost:8081/?#/login